# Raspberry 4B Composite video issue

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, config.txt, composite-video, rca

Need your help with the Raspberry 4B Composite video issue. I have read official documentation and a lot of topics on the internet, but still did not solve my problem.

Problem:

- I power Raspberry -> Rainbow screen apears -> Welcome to Raspberry Pi Desktop picture with logs -> After "NetworkManagerdispatcher.service" screen blank.

Input:

- Raspberry is working with HDMI.
- RCA TRRS jack cabel I have made regarding pinout from docs and checked it with the multimeter.

Background:

- I have experimented with different recommendations, but after implementation of

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d,composite
enable_tvout=1
```

behavior same, despite different additional commands and their combination.

My config file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
#display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d

#----------------------------------------------
#Added 12.02.24
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
#enable_tvout=1
#----------------------------------------------

#max_framebuffers=2

#-----------------------------------------------
#Added 17.02.24
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d,composite
enable_tvout=1
framebuffer_width=580
framebuffer_height=360 
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=1
disable_overscan=1
audio_pwm_mode=2
hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1
#-----------------------------------------------

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
##disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
##disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]
```

And cmdline file:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7361835e-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet video=Composite-1:720x480@60ie splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=UA vc4.tv_norm=PAL
```